# Inject a module into karma test in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-injector

I am trying to upgrade my Angular app from 1.3.x to 1.5.1. I have a suite of tests that all ran fine with Karma + PhantomJS when I was at version 1.3.x of Angular, however once I upgraded all of my tests are failing. It appears that the way I was injecting modules into the unit tests before no longer works.

This fails in 1.5:

```
'use strict'
 App = null

 fdescribe 'App Model', ->
   beforeEach module('MyAngularApp')

   beforeEach inject ($injector)->
     App = $injector.get('App')

 it 'should exist', ->
   console.log 'App:', App
   expect(App).toBeDefined()
```

I have also tried injecting with the following

```
 beforeEach inject ($injector, _App_)->
   App = _App_
```

but my App model is still not being injected.

I have been digging through the documentation on AngularJS 1.5.1 but I didn't see any changes that I need to make with the injector.

In Angular 1.5.x, how can I properly inject a model into my unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it looks like the issue was actually that the upgrade caused a second copy of `angular-mocks` to be bundled up into the app. I'm not sure whether this came from AngularJS, Karma, or PhantomJS but removing the `angular-mock.js` file from the files included in the configuration of `karma.conf.js` fixed the issue. It seems like the PhantomJS error logs just didn't provide enough insight into what the actual issue was.

For anyone else experiencing this issue, I noticed that changing the browser I was testing in to Chrome (instead of PhantomJS 2) resulted in a different error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngLocale due to:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

That lead me to the solution here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11303

Comment: Was having a similar issue where `inject` didn't seem to work, it was not related to `angular-mocks` though, but changing the browser to `Chrome` gave me error messages that made sense so I could fix it.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked for me - thanks! To be clear: the problem is that angular-mock.js is being included twice.  (Once in a bundle, once in the karma config), if you include it only once, the error goes away.